# How to initialise an array of pointers to NULL that's inside a struct, and the struct is within an array of other structs

Tags: c

So I have a structure that has an array of pointers inside (to another struct).
I was trying to initialise that array to NULL but it seems you can't do it in C.
How do you initialise the array Rpr to NULL?

I tried to do it the other way like you see in the code below, but it doesnt work.

```
typedef struct {maillon *Rpr [7];} repere;
repere R[26];

for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
   R[i].Rpr={NULL};
}
```

it pops some random insignificant errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C distinguishes between assignment (which is an expression) and initialization (which is part of the definition of a variable). In particular, the `= { ... }` syntax is only valid for initialization.

If you want to do this with a separate loop, you need two nested loops (or a lot of repeated code to set all the elements):

```
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<7; j++) {
        R[i].Rpr[j] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just use initialization:

```
repere R[26] = { { { NULL } } };
```

Technically this only initializes the first element of the inner array in the struct in the first element of the outer array, but C has no "half-initialized" variables. The rule is that if there's an initializer that doesn't cover all of the variable's fields, they are implicitly set to zero. For pointers that means they're all null pointers.

In fact, this "initialize everything with 0" initializer can be made both shorter and more generic:

```
repere R[26] = { 0 };
```

This `{ 0 }` initializer works for other types as well. (Some compilers warn about this construct ("*missing braces in initializer*" and similar). Those compilers are stupid and need to stop.)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
       R[i].Rpr[j]=NULL;
}
```

But you can skip the loop completely by writing `repere R[26]={0};` That will init the whole memory of the struct to zero, irregardless of how many fields there are or what type they are.

Comment: it says "error: assignment to expression with array type"

Comment: so that means the elements of the array of pointers will be set to NULL?!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method of

```
   memset(R, 0, sizeof(R));
```

Comment: Simple, but technically non-portable (it requires null pointers to have all bits as zero, which may not be an issue in practice).

Comment: I do not know any platform in common use with null pointers not having all bits set to zero, even if (void)0 is a valid address or reference (for example ARM cortex where at this address is initial sp value

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed, Here

```
maillon *Rpr [7];
```

`Rpr` is *array of pointers of `maillon` type* and you need to initialize each pointers with `NULL`. For e.g

```
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<7; j++) { /* Rpr is array of 7 pointers, so rotate 7 times */
        R[i].Rpr[j] = NULL; /* initializing each Rpr[index] with NULL */
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought of it, but I was looking for a cleaner way of doing it.